# Passing output from C++ to PHP

Tags: php, c++, integration, output

I am creating a PHP file to pass values to a c++ .exe which will then calculate an output and return that output. However, I cannot seem to get the output from the .exe back into the PHP file.

PHP Code:

```
$path = 'C:enter code here\Users\sumit.exe';
$handle = popen($path,'w');
$write = fwrite($handle,"37");
pclose($handle);
```

C++ Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Declaation of Input Variables:
int main()
{
int num;
cin>> num;

std::cout<<num+5;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C++ code I am not seeing anything for passing variables in you need

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

instead of

```
 int main()
```

Remember argc is the count of variables and it includes the path to the file, so your arguments begin at 1 with each argv being a c-string of that argument.  If you need a decimal atof is your friend or atoi for an integer.

Then you are using popen.  [The PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) says that it can be only used for reading or writting.   It is not bi-directional.  You want to use [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to have bi-directional support.

Anyways, This is how I would write your C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

// Declaation of Input Variables:
int main(int arc, char* argv[])
{
   int num;
   num = atoi(argv[1]);

   std::cout<<num+5;
   return 0;
 }
```

**Note:** I removed `using namespace std` because I noticed you were still trying to use the namespace in the main function (i.e. `std::cout`) and it better to keep it out of a global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise neither `system` nor `popen` but `proc_open` command: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Call it like

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr, also a pipe the child will write to
);
proc_open('C:enter code here\Users\sumit.exe', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

After that you'll have `$pipes` filled with handles to send data to program (`[0]`) and recieve data from program (`[1]`). Also you will have `[2]` which you can use to get stderr from the program (or just close if you don't use stderr).

Don't forget to close process handle with `proc_close()` and pipe handles with `fclose()`. Note that your program will not know the output is complete before you close `$pipes[0]` handle or write some whitespace character. I advise closing the pipe.

Using command line arguments in `system()` or `popen()` is valid, though if you intend to send large amounts of data and/or raw data, you will have trouble with command line length limits and with escaping special chars.

Answer (score 0):

you are writing into exe file, you should pass your argument like

```
system("C:enter code here\Users\sumit.exe 37");
```

Comment: You need to change the definition of main() in the sample, too. int main(int argc, char **argv) or int main(int argc, char *argv[])